# When drawing a category, is it reasonable to imply composition?

Tags: category-theory

I found this representation of a category.
[image: Mother child category]
I find the equation at the top quite redoundant.

My reasoning is that everything is depicted except for the identities. If I want to compose `mother` with `firstChild` I can only use what I find in the picture. That would leave me with the identity $id_{Mother}$.

Is the equation at the top necessary? Or is it just an aid?

Comment: The word part `first` is redundant as well when there is only one child. I find this whole  example extremely awful

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen well no, you cannot assume there is only one child.

Comment: Why not? The illustration seems to imply that the class of objects has exactly two elements (you say yourself that "everything is depicted ... "). Apparently, object `Child` is the `firstChild` of object `Mother`, and under very mild biological assumptions, neither `Child `nor `Mother` can be a `secondChild` of `Mother`

Comment: There are two objects but in this context they represent sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The convention I've commonly seen is that that every path of morphisms composes to a distinct morphism unless otherwise implied by indicated compositions. So without the composition equation, the diagram would most commonly be read so that $\cdots\neq(\mathrm{mother}\circ\mathrm{firstChild})\circ(\mathrm{mother}\circ\mathrm{firstChild})\neq\mathrm{mother}\circ\mathrm{firstChild}\neq\mathrm{id}_{\mathrm{Mother}}$.

You can get around mentioning the equation if you say something like "category with two non-identity morphisms" which would force $\mathrm{mother}\circ\mathrm{firstChild}=\mathrm{id}_{\mathrm{Mother}}$ and $\mathrm{firstChild}\circ\mathrm{mother}=\mathrm{id}_{\mathrm{Child}}$. But either way, you have to say something to indicate how one is supposed to compose.

Comment: So it's akin to "this is just a graph, the category i'm *really* talking about is freely generated from this" at which point I would have to give the equation. Makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Note that in this interpretation from the given diagram, $firstChild \circ Mother \ne \operatorname{id}_{Child}$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler yes but that's possible because, given a child X, the first child of the mother of X may not be X.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I think in gurghet's diagram Child and Mother are types whose terms are mothers and children, hence mother and firstChild are to be interpreted as functions sending children to mothers and mothers to children.